# Destruct Codeigniter Library Before View Output

Tags: codeigniter, destructor, php

I have a custom Library in Codeigniter that creates session cookies on destruct.

```
public function __destruct()
{
    $this->CI->session->set_userdata('user', $this->user);
}
```

This fails because the headers have already been sent by the view before the class is destructed.

I know I can manually destruct the library before the view is outputed.  My question is, is it possible to have my libraries destruct automatically before any headers are sent?

Is there a hook I can use or some functionality in codeigniter that destroys all libraries/models?

**EDIT**

After some trial and error, I found I can't manually destruct the library at the point I need. I tried a few approaches but the library still remains within scope and can't be unset.

Comment: Is there a reason you want this to happen on `__destruct()`?

Comment: @complex857 Yes. My application sets and gets information from CI sessions and since I store session data in a database, I want to only commit changes at the end of the app. Instead of relying on controllers to remember to store the session, I wanted to store it on cleanup.

Comment: Can't you just hook this up to one of the hooks? Like `post_controller`, or `post_controller_constructor`? Your header sending problem might be avoided if you move the rendering into a post_controller hook too. As far as i know, CI don't really do explicit teardown, just lets php take care of that after everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

You must use HOOKS. Just enable it in config.php, than, add new Hook into your Hooks folder. And don't forget to add info, about where to load in the hooks.php on CONFIG dir.